# Change (&) in url to (-) with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Can't find the solution. Of course I want to change the (`=`) as well.

I have look and have searched for any examples but could not find anything.

This is what I have:

```
/family/vicks&record=john&generation=10
```

I would like:

```
/family/vicks-record-john-generation-10.php
```

Comment: `/family/vicks&record=john&generation=10` - that looks a bit _odd_, can you please confirm that that is the actual URL (ie. there is no _query string_)? And how is this URL currently being handled/routed? `/family/vicks-record-john-generation-10.php` - so you've created a `.php` file of that name? What URL are you currently linking to? What do you currently have in your `.htaccess` file? Have you tried _anything_? (Why is the question tagged "mysql"? Or "php" for that matter?)

Comment: It is an odd url. I am pulling from a php file and a mysql database at the same time. I can fix everything but the "&" in the file...

Comment: So, the `=` is now "fixed"? What about the other questions I asked in my comment? It sounds like this is the URL you are generating internally and consequently linking to in your pages? If so, then this isn't something you would fix with `.htaccess`. (?)